# $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ over finite commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, lie-algebras, finite-fields

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unit $1$. Assume that $n > 2$.

Is it true that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(R)$ is not nilpotent or solvable?

It is well known that if char$F = 2$, then $\mathfrak{sl}_2(F)$ is nilpotent.
But I am interested in the case $n > 2$.

Comment: Do your rings have unity?

Comment: Yes, they do. So we can use all standard bases. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is positive at least for finite fields.
For a finite field $F$ of characteristic $p>0$, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$ is simple for $p\nmid n$. For $p\mid n$, its center $Z$ is $1$-dimensional and consists of the scalar multiples of the identity. However, then $\mathfrak{psl}_n(F)=\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)/F$ is simple for $n\ge 3$, so that $\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$ cannot be solvable for $p\mid n$ and $n\ge 3$. 
Perhaps the argument can be extended to $\mathfrak{sl}_n(R)$ over a commutative ring $R$ with unit.

Comment: Since $R$ has a unit 1, can we prove that $[\mathfrak{sl}_n(R), \mathfrak{sl}_n(R)] = \mathfrak{sl}_n(R)$ direactly by showing that every standard basis can be obtained from the bracket of some two bases? So it is not solvable.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Take $n=2$. Then we need to assume that $2$ is a unit in $R$, in order to conclude that $[\mathfrak{sl}_2(R),\mathfrak{sl}_2(R)]=\mathfrak{sl}_2(R)$.

Comment: I have already assumed that $n > 2$.

Comment: For $i \neq j$, $ E_{ij} = [E_{ik}, E_{kj}] $ for some $ k\neq i, j $ and $E_{ii}-E_{i+1, i +1} = [E_{i, i+1}, E_{i+1, i}]$.  If $n>2$, we have such a $k$. I dont know how we need $n$ to be a unit. May be I am wrong.

Comment: Using the Chevalley basis for $\mathbb{sl}_3(R)$, the coefficients I obtain for the Lie brackets are in $\{0,\pm1,\pm 2\}$. Then I would need again that $2$ is a unit in $R$. Is there a basis such that all coefficients are in $0,\pm1\}$?